# Time out expired in list

Tags: c#, list, exception, timeout

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void Getindividualdrugs()
    {
        try
        {
            string json = "";
            List<DataRow> id = new List<DataRow>();
            List<individual_drugsCLS> indi = new List<individual_drugsCLS>();
            using (individual_drugsCLS ids = new individual_drugsCLS())
            {
                id = ids.getAll();
                if (id.Count == 0)
                {
                    ids.error = "Sorry ! No Individual Drugs found";
                    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ids);

                }
                else
                {

                    foreach (DataRow Txt in id)
                    {
                        using (individual_drugsCLS individual = new individual_drugsCLS())
                        {


                            individual.title = Convert.ToString(Txt["title"]);
                            individual.individual_id = Convert.ToInt64(Txt["individual_id"]);
                            indi.Add(individual);
                        }


                    }
                    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(indi);
                    response1.Write(json);

                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Hello i have webmethod i am getting 155 records in this one but after 82 records its hangs up and throws exception

> *Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.*

I don't know what i am doing wrong

Comment: ids.getAll() method is using DataReader to read data from database ?

Comment: on new of individual_drugsCLS (i.e. individual_drugsCLS individual = new individual_drugsCLS()) is there any connection related logic is written which keeping connection of database to open ?

Comment: ya actually i don't have closed my connection that was the error sorry for late reply

Comment: Okay. So, you need to just close connection or put connection open or close logic in function which required to perform database operation rather than on new of class.